# Deadlock when updating table in MSSQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I need to delete all external links from "Content" column.

```
<?php

require_once('phpQuery-onefile.php');

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"database", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"pass");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( 'server', $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {

}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$query = "SELECT ArticleId, Content FROM Articles WHERE Content LIKE '%href%';";
$stmt=sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);

if (!$stmt) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {    
    $cont_old = $row['Content'];
    $ch = false;
    $dom = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($cont_old, 'cp1251');
    foreach ($dom->find('a') as $a) {
        $a = pq($a);
        if (strpos($a->attr('href'), '/biblio/') === false) {
            $ch = true;
            print "link = " . iconv('CP1251', 'CP866//IGNORE', $a->attr('href') . " -> " . $a->html()) ."\n";
            $a = pq($a);
            $a->replaceWith($a->html());
        }
    }
    $cont = $dom->htmlOuter();


    if ($ch) {
        $sql2 = 'UPDATE Articles SET content = ? WHERE ArticleId = ?';
        $stmt2 = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql2, array(&$cont, &$row['ArticleId']));
        if( sqlsrv_execute( $stmt2 ) === false ) {
            print "id={$row['ArticleId']} ERROR: ";
            print_r( sqlsrv_errors());
            print "\n";
        } else {
            print "updated id={$row['ArticleId']}\n";
        }

    }
}

sqlsrv_close($conn);

print "END\n";
```

This throws error:

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Transaction
>   (Process ID 60) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer |
>   generic waitable object resources with another process and has been
>   chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

Comment: Deadlock happens when someone else is also accessing the database and both of the processes want to access the row locked by the other process.

Comment: are you starting a transaction/lock with the select query? Since you're then trying to update the very same record you just fetched, you could be causing a deadlock. update can't proceed until the select finishes, and the select can't finish because you're hung on the update.

Comment: Making an UPDATE statement in a loop is not a good pattern. Try to make one single update.